# Communication between Java ServerSocket and javascript Websocket

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, serversocket

I want to create a server in java on my computer, and then connect to that server from my phone via its browser. I also want to be able to send messages back and forth between the phone (browser) and the computer (server), so I can update what is displayed in the browser.

My plan is to create java server using a ServerSocket. When the phone connects to localhost:port in the browser, the Server will sent some html and javascript code that should start a websocket. I am am able to display standard html elements in the browser etc, but when I try to Start a websocket, I get this error:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`

Is this the correct approach. Can I achive this in some other way?

This is my code.

```
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {

        final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
                    System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("Waiting");
                        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Unable to process client request");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
        serverThread.start();
    }

    private class ClientTask implements Runnable {

        private final Socket clientSocket;

        private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Got a client !");

            PrintWriter out = null;
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());


            /*out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            out.println("\r\n");
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("    <head>");
            out.println("        <title>Test</title>");
            out.println("        <script type=\"text/javascript\">");
            out.println("          var w = new WebSocket(\"ws://192.168.0.5:8000\")");
            out.println("....More code");
            out.println("        </script>");
            out.println("    </head>");
            out.println("    <body>");
            out.println("    </body>");
            out.println("</html>");*/

                out.print("Hej");
                out.flush();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ;

            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hej");
        new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely it's because you don't return proper websocket handshake response https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_a_WebSocket_server_in_Java#Handshaking

Answer (score 0):

To write a Websocket server you need to implement the Websocket protocol which involves upgrading an http connection.
Even if you can write a program to do this from scratch, there are some libraries / frameworks you can use that resolve most of the connection part.

The two that come to my head are to use or any Java EE container implementing (JSR 356) (java EE 7 and 8 implement it), there are some tutorial for this alternative using Spring Boot, and the other I can remember is to use Netty.

On the client side, if connecting with a browser, the client code will be written in javascript. You will only need to write java code for the client if you want to connect from a java program instead of a browser (which based on your question is not your case).

Some links that may help you:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/websocket.htm
https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring
https://netty.io/